# Rails: Unknown attribute during model create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have an error message - "unknown attribute :news_id" but I can't understand where the problem is. I have news controller and I want to create comments for every news. I hope that someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

schema.rb

```
create_table "comments", :primary_key => "ID", :force => true do |t| 
  t.integer "Author_ID" 
  t.integer "News_ID", :null => false 
  t.string "Content", :limit => 500, :null => false 
  t.datetime "Date", :null => false 
end
```

Comment model:

```
belongs_to :news
```

News model:

```
has_many :comments
```

Comment: It could be a issue with Rails' pluralization stuff. The `Comment` model has a field called `new_id` ?

Comment: My comment table has these columns - ID, News_ID, Content

Answer (score 8):

This is because you have not added `:news_id` to your `Comment`'s model.

Write the migration to add news_id to Comment and your problem will be solved.

Comment: add attr_accessible :news_id in the comment model but still don't work

Comment: That would be my primary guess, as well; we can't be sure, though, because you didn't show your `schema.rb`.

Comment: create_table "comments", :primary_key => "ID", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "Author_ID"
    t.integer  "News_ID",                  :null => false
    t.string   "Content",   :limit => 500, :null => false
    t.datetime "Date",                     :null => false
  end

Comment: it need to be  t.integer :news_id ,not  t.integer News_ID

Answer (score 1):

You can print out the params by `puts params` in starting of your `create` action to check the actual attributes it is sending.

or you can check out the routes you are having for comment create action to get the parameter..

Comment: When I print with puts params in create action I don't see the hash, I have the error message. Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: you doing it in first line of the action... before using the params[:news_id] .. and you need to check the output in rails console (if using webrick server)

Comment: I am using Aptana studio and I there is nothing in the console

Comment: can you run `rake routes` and post the result here... (for comments controller related routes)

Comment: news_comments GET    /news/:news_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                  POST   /news/:news_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_news_comment GET    /news/:news_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new

Comment: edit_news_comment GET    /news/:news_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     news_comment GET    /news/:news_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                  PUT    /news/:news_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  DELETE /news/:news_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same issue when working on a Ruby on Rails application with a PostgreSQL database in production.

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was that I added some new columns to the table(s) in my **development environment** using new migration files that I generated, but when I made a push to the **production environment**, I didn't create those new columns via migration too.

All I had to do was to simply run a database migration in the **production environment** to create those new columns using the migration files that were generated in the **development environment**.

```
rails db:migrate
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**